# Ruby on Rails: Handling global constants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, activerecord

I am working on a Ruby on Rails Application with a React Frontend.

I currently have constants that are needed on both the backend and frontend. In order to not have these diverge and to be able to manage them in one place, we store them in our `config/initializer` files on the backend. We have a `ConstantsController` which serves these to the frontend.

This has been great so far but now, some of the constants are out of date. E.g. for a `color` constant, we no longer have some colors available and don't want to show them on the frontend. However, if we change the constants(removing unused ones) we will break some validations.

Right now I can only think of having an `Active` set of constants that are sent to the frontend which is a subset of the `Full` set of constants. Otherwise I imagine defining the constants in a table with a disabled field and having a Model for each constant. On the frontend we would only display `active` constants in this case

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. There's no one "right" way--and if an "old" value can be sent back from the front end (e.g., during an edit process) without being corrected to an "ok" value you'll still have validation errors, meaning some sort of backfill/fixup chore would need to be run. What makes the most sense is context dependent.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "we will break some validation errors"?

Comment: I would probally try to find other words for what your trying to do - "global" and "constant" have some very specific conations in programming. If you rephrase it as for example "App wide settings used on the front and back end"  that makes it a lot easier to actually discuss different possible solutions which could be anything from a YAML/JSON file, a database table or two or something like memcached.

Comment: And as pointed out by @DaveNewton there isn't really a "right" way to handle configuration and this question might be closed as its primarily opinion based. You might want to do some reseach on how different devs have approached the problem and maybe ask a question on a forum like http://reddit.com/r/rubyonrails which is open for discussions.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that anything that I'm referring to as a constant is not a constant if it is changing. These should instead be handled as settings/types/versions which are stored in tables